# Pytest: Correct way to Mock a function called within a function to return what was passed into it

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I am new to Pytest and am trying to figure out how to make a function called within a function perform nothing.

Here's an example that illustrates my overall goal.

```
def add_one(n):
    return n+1

def add_eleven(n):
    n = add_one(n)
    return n+10
```

Then testing would have `add_one` return whatever number passed into when I test the function `add_eleven`

```
from module import add_one, add_eleven

from unittest.mock import patch

def test_add_one():
    n = add_one(0)
    
    assert 1 == n

@patch('module.add_one')
def test_add_eleven(mock_add_one):
    mock_add_one.return_value = # Unsure what to do...

    n = add_eleven(0)
    
    assert 10 == n
```

Comment: Why are you asserting `10 == n`, when `add_eleven(0)` is supposed to return `11`? Do you want to force `mock_add_one` to return `0` even when the argument is `0`?

Comment: @blhsing because I want to create a unit test for `add_eleven` that does not depend on `add_one` working correctly

Comment: In that case, wouldn't `mock_add_one.return_value = 0` work for you?

Comment: @blhsing for this specific situation yes, but for what I am trying to do it will not work. I want something dynamic

Comment: Then you need to update your sample code with enough moving parts to sufficiently illustrate exactly how dynamic you want the mocked `add_one` to be. As it is it's hard to imagine where the difficulty lies for you.

Comment: You are testing `add_one` already, you should not test the implementation of `add_eleven` just that it produces the expected results depending on the input.

Comment: Why do you need to mock? Can you not just pass in the dependency (here `add_one` is the dependency) as a function parameter? That way you can use a different version (e.g. a fake or a stub, using standard test double nomenclature) for tests.

Comment: @ndc85430 can you provide an answer illustrating your point?